# Rails docs methods differ from their implementation with left/right colons, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

As far as I can tell, this correct way to write this line of code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

However, in the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery), it states that **`:with`**, "Set[s] the method to handle unverified request", and **`:exception`** is an "unverified request handling method". Why is the colon for the `:with` on the left side in the doc? It's on that side when listing **all** the valid options for this method (`:only/:except`, `:prepend`, etc.), but not when using them. If I hadn't looked at the example on the page, I wouldn't have known how to write the method. Is there some pattern here I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:with` is a [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html).

`with: :exception` is a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html), a simplified version of `{ with: :exception }`.

When listing valid options, all valid keys of the hash passed as options are mentioned. The keys are symbols, but they need to be passed along with a value, such as `:exception`.

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

is essentialy the same as

```
protect_from_forgery({ with: :exception })
```

Comment: Ahh, I see now in the docs, it says "`protect_from_forgery`(options = {})", so it takes a hash, and keys are symbols. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Clarifications: The braces may be omitted only when the hash is the last argument to a method. In a hash literal, when they key is a Symbol, the colon may follow so `m a: :b` is the same as `m({ a: :b })` is the same as `m(:a => :b)` (but, depending on what `a` really is, quotes may be needed for the JavaScript-style version, eg: `{@a: 6}` is invalid whereas `{:@a => 6}` and `{'@a': 6}` are fine (assuming you're using a recent version of Ruby)).

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that!